# Creating Data Table in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I will admit I am new to C#, but I am just trying to create a new data table in my code. I have added `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to my References and included the:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Here is a snapshot of what my code looks like

```
namespace ExcelReading
{
    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        }
    }
}
```

The `new dataTabel()` is underlined in red and the error say:

Cannot create and instance of the abstract class or interface 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable'

Why is this? What do I have to do to create this data table?

I am using VS 2012, .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: you first need to learn the concept of OOP.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with DataTable?

Comment: Are you actually trying to create an Excel Table or are you simply trying to create a System.Data.DataTable? There's a huge difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Cannot create and instance of the abstract class or interface
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable'

Error itself explains why you can't create instant of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable.`

You mean `System.Data.DataTable`? then do as below

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter then there may be conflict of DaTaTable, may want to use aliases

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to create a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the `System.Data` namespace.

```
using System.Data;
```

So you have to decide what you need more, the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` or the `System.Data` namespace. Remove the other, otherwise you have a conflict.

You can also specify the fully qualified path to the class, for example:

```
var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
```

[**Using Namespaces (C# Programming Guide)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx)